# Javascript Moving Ball Exercise

Tags: javascript

I need some help understanding the solutions to an exercise my development bootcamp had us complete last week. The problem is simple, move the "ball" (created in a 'div' in html) on a diagonal trajectory back and forth. Below is the solution. What i'm having trouble understanding is the "if" statement at the very end. According to the solution, if the position of the ball is  either equal to 0 or greater then the edge defined by Xmax or Ymax, reverse = !reverse. Since reverse was initially set to false as a global variable does that mean if those criteria are met that the global value of reverse changes?

```
                      // BALL MOVING EXERCISE (WEEK 2) // 


//Set global variable that would contain the position, velocity and the html element "ball"
// CREATE DIV "BALL" IN HTML - COPY/PASTE TO BODY TAG

  #ball{
    height: 50px;
    width : 50px;
    background : black;
    border-radius : 50%;
    position : absolute;
    left: ;
    top: ;
    }

var positionX = 0;
var positionY = 0;
var velocity = 100;
var reverse = false;
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");

//write a function that can change the position of the html element "ball"
function moveBall() {
  // two x-axis coordinates
  var Xmin = 0;
  var Xmax = 300;

  // two y-axis coordinates
  var Ymin = 0;
  var Ymax = 300;

  if (reverse) {
    positionX = positionX - velocity;
    positionY = positionY - velocity;
    ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
    ball.style.top = positionY + "px";
  } else {
    positionX = positionX + velocity;
    positionY = positionY + velocity;
    ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
    ball.style.top = positionY + "px";
  }

  if (
    positionX > Xmax ||
    positionX === Xmin ||
    positionY > Ymax ||
    positionY === Ymin
  ) {
    reverse = !reverse;
  }
}
setInterval(moveBall, 100);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, it changes the value. Why not add a `console.log` or `debugger` call here and inspect its value?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still new to JS so i'm not familiar with the debugger call. Console.log would obviously show the value of reverse in the console. This feels like one of those duh moments.